# Target container is not a DOM element React.js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have had a look at all the other posts that have had this issue, but I am still confused as to why I am running into this error.  I made sure I used id in my

Just started playing with React, so I am sure its something quite silly.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Code is below.

index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="testing"></div>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('testing'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

Full Error message:

invariant

```
../app/node_modules/fbjs/lib/invariant.js:42 renderSubtreeIntoContainer
../app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:15144 render
../app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:15254
▲ 3 stack frames were expanded.
./src/index.js
../app/src/index.js:6
  3 | import './index.css';
  4 | import App from './App';
  5 | 
> 6 | ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('testing'));
  7 | 
  8 | 
  9 | 
View compiled
▼ 6 stack frames were expanded.
__webpack_require__
../app/webpack/bootstrap 4755e61baeec1360d412:678
fn
../app/webpack/bootstrap 4755e61baeec1360d412:88
0
http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:35264:18
__webpack_require__
../app/webpack/bootstrap 4755e61baeec1360d412:678
./node_modules/ansi-regex/index.js.module.exports
../app/webpack/bootstrap 4755e61baeec1360d412:724
(anonymous function)
http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:728:10
```

Comment: Post the whole error message please.

Comment: Try removing the `<script src="index.js"></script>` from index.html if you are using `create-react-app` boilerplate.

Comment: Yes I tried that and it didnt help, as I saw that others didnt have it, and yes I used the create-react-app boilerplate.  If I change the "testing" to "root" it works but I dont know why adjusting to any other name would make a difference.

Comment: Make sure the html you are seeing in your browser is the right index.html. Webpack might serve another one from cache.

Comment: I just opened a new google chrome in incognito mode to see if caching would be an issue, but still see the same issue.  Do I have to add index.html somewhere in the js file?  Or does the same name signify which is loaded?

Comment: Webpack sometimes doesn't serve the files your are seeing in your folders but serves files from memory, inspect your html in chrome to see if the id="testing" div really is there.

Comment: What's in 'react.js'? If it's your Webpack bundle output move it below the div id='testing' in your body.

Comment: I removed react.js, I was going through other tutorials and saw people added it.  But removing it doesnt remove the problem, but I have removed it as it made no difference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158786/discussion-between-xdreamcoding-and-godspped).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure to double check the index.html you are seeing in your browser. Assuming you use create-react-app an thereby webpack it might serve you a different file either from memory or from the public folder.

*Mistake was found from discussion in comments and chat.*

Comment: yea totally my mistake.  when using create-react-app, it creates a public folder, thats where the html is, I had created a html in the src folder which was not being loaded...  

Thanks for all the help.  When changing the right index.html page in the public folder everything worked.

Comment: In my case I had double <html><head>...</head><body></body></html> block generated by copy and past. After deleting the bad block error is solved!!! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `React.createElement()` like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(<App />), document.getElementById('testing'));
```

Comment: `ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);` from official React Docs. So i doubt. EDIT: Well he isn't using jsx so you might still have a point here, sorry.

Comment: Target container is not a DOM element.
▶ 3 stack frames were collapsed.
./src/index.js
../app/src/index.js:6
  3 | import './index.css';
  4 | import App from './App';
  5 | 
> 6 | ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(<App />), document.getElementById('testing'));

Answer (score 0):

Check in your html file if the id attribute has the same name as

```
ReactDOM.render(, document.getElementById('index'));
```