# basic ReactJS "Target container is not a DOM element" error

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have the below `index.js` file:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Aggregator extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
    <div>
    <p>Hello world</p>
  </div>

  );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
  <Aggregator/>
</div>,
    document.getElementById('content')
);
```

The HTML file that I am trying to link the above JS file to is `index.html`. The HTML file is given below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="content"></div>
  <script src ="./index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I get a `"Target container is not a DOM element"` error. I am not sure whether the Javascript file is correctly linked in or what could be the other source of error.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Update: The problem seems to be the same as given in [Target container is not a DOM element React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47244575). But the original question identifies the root cause of the problem but does not mention the solution.

Comment: Are u using webpack?How did u created your react-app?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Target container is not a DOM element React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47244575/target-container-is-not-a-dom-element-react-js)

Comment: I created my react-app using `create-react-app`

Comment: Yes, am using webpack